# copy constructor in prototype.js

Tags: javascript, class, prototypejs, copy-constructor

In prototype.js you can create classes e.g. like this:

```
var MyClass = Class.create(
{
    initialize: function (par1, par2)
    {
        this.data = $R(par1, par2).toArray();
    }
});
```

and instantiate them through

```
var myObj = new MyClass(1, 7000);
```

Now, how can I copy this object? The following does not work:

```
var myObj2 = MyObj.clone();
```

In my specific case, I only need a shallow copy, i.e. the attributes of the instance can reference the same objects. Some way of defining a copy constructor would certainly be the most versatile option.

Is that possible? (Preferably without relying on prototype.js internals)

Comment: `var myObj2 = Object.create(myObj)`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: That's less-than-shallow

Comment: @Bergi: I don’t think this is a duplicate. Notice that I inquire about the class system of the prototype.js framework, not general javascript objects.

Comment: @canaaerus: If I understood you correctly, you wanted to do it without prototype.js, so it's just a standard js object to copy?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: Thank you – that seems to work. (Even though Object.create is not specific to prototype.js) Maybe you could add this as an answer together with a short explanation.

Comment: @Bergi: I meant without internals / implementation details, i.e. just using the prototype.js API. But a simplistic solution like Raj’s is close enough.

Comment: @canaaerus Ah, I see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Prototype's `Object.extend`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Object/extend/) (or the native ES6 `Object.assign`) to copy your properties onto a new instance of your class:

```
var MyClass = Class.create({
    initialize: function (par1, par2) {
        this.data = $R(par1, par2).toArray();
    },
    clone: function() {
        return Object.extend(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)), this);
    }
});
```